# How to get channels of a particular in IRC

Tags: android, irc

I am developing an IRC client and I want to list all the channels of a particular server in a listview.

When the user selects a particular channel, conversation activity will be started.

Can any one help me how to get channel list of particular server.

Comment: There are many Java IRC libraries. Just pick one that suits you and works on Android: https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+irc+library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See RFC 1459, you want `LIST` https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-4.2.6

Comment: Note that LIST isn't 100% reliable. Some servers deny its use within N seconds of initial connection (to prevent spam bots) and that most will throttle its output and some will expect a filtering parameter to narrow the search. It really *should* be deprecated from the spec, but isnt.